# Wrong amplitude values after the FFT

Tags: matlab, fft

At the plot of the code that written below, i should see amplitude between values of 75 to 200 uV but there is something strange in my plot, can you help me and advise, what wrong with my code and how can i correct that ?

Thank you all

**Here is the code :**

```
clear all;
close all;
Fs = 200
t= 0:1/Fs:180
y_in=zeros (1, length(t));
  for  i = 1:18
F = randi ([4 7], 1);% frequency
A = randi ([75 200],1);% amplitude A=75~200 uV.
y_tmp =A*sin (2*pi*F*t);
 y_in=y_in+ y_tmp;
  end;
L=length (y_in);
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y_new = fft(y_in,NFFT)/L;
f_new = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

figure(1)
plot(f_new,2*abs(Y_new(1:NFFT/2+1))) ;
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y_in(t)')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('|y_in(f)|')
```

Comment: What **are** you seeing?  Can you post images?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looping 18 times and use

```
F = randi([4 7],1);
```

some of the frequencies that build up the final signal occurs multiple times, hence their amplitudes are added to each other.

What you're seeing after the fft in your plot is therefore the sum of the amplitudes for the frequencies

```
F = 4, 5, 6, 7 Hz
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer.

how can I decompose the sum of the amplitude ?
i mean, after the FFT i need to see the amplitude between values of 75 to 200 uV

can you please suggest me what should i do ?

thanks.

Comment: If you take `F` out of the loop and instead define it as `F=linspace(4,7,18);` you would get what you are asking for.